# ¿Cómo puedo obtener el código asociado a una pull request?

Tags: git, github, git-clone

Estoy realizando un proyecto en el cual necesito concretamente una "Pull request" en lugar del código de la branch principal.

¿Cómo puedo "clonar" u "obtener" el código asociado a esa "pull request"?

- URL del repositorio: https://github.com/worldveil/dejavu
- URL de la pull request: https://github.com/worldveil/dejavu/pull/78

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De [Modifying an inactive pull request locally](https://help.github.com/articles/checking-out-pull-requests-locally/), tienes que la manera es:

```
git fetch origin pull/ID/head:BRANCHNAME
```

En este caso, por tanto, debes bajarte el repositorio original y luego hacer un *fetch* (traerte, vaya) esa pull request:

```bash
git clone https://github.com/worldveil/dejavu
git fetch origin pull/78/head:tu_rama
```

---

Manera manual:

Una pull request es una petición de incorporar un código en otro. En este caso particular, el usuario [tjj5036](https://github.com/tjj5036) quiere añadir algo en el repositorio [dejavu](https://github.com/worldveil/dejavu). Para hacer esto, debe crear una rama en algún sitio y solicitar incorporarla en dejavu.

En la pull request se ve el texto:

> tjj5036  wants to merge 2 commits into worldveil:master from tjj5036:postgres_isolated_redo

Esto quiere decir que los cambios los hizo tjj5036 en su repositorio de github https://github.com/tjj5036/dejavu/ y, en particular, en la rama `postgres_isolated_redo`.

Lo que tienes que hacer pues es bajarte ese repositorio y mover a esa rama:

```bash
git clone https://github.com/tjj5036/dejavu
git checkout postgres_isolated_redo
```

Veo que la rama tiene un commit de más que no aparece en la pull request, por lo que para ir al código exacto de la pull deberás ir a:

```
git checkout 99e4120410d2b9f5c395193d293d11ecfa5ca6d4
```

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que identificar el hash del comit para apuntar a este, lo haces de esta manera:

En la imagen puedes ver el inicio de la cadena hash necesaria para apuntar a esta, es un alfanumerico de 7 digitos aproximadamente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tambien puedes identificar el hash de los commit desd ela consola con

```
git log
```

alli veras algo como esto

```
commit 99e4120410d2b9f5c395193d293d11ecfa5ca6d4
Author: XXXX <XXXX@XXXX.(tjj5036)>
Date:   16 Mar 2015
```

donde los primeros 7 caracteres son los que necesitas del comit, posteriormente tipeas en tu consola:

```
git checkout 99e4120
```

Entonces tu HEAD estará apuntando hacia commit que necesitas siendo el resultado que necesitas.